# Auto rendered images from external links

Tags: media

I'm trying to make a functionality for users, so when they add a link in a body of some article(in text editor with other text), it displays as an image.
Any ideas?
Thanks)

Comment: you would have to override hook_node_presave or hook_node_save and filter the text from the given field - when it detects a valid image type it would change the link into an <img> tag

Answer (score 0):

[CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) has the ability to add an image to a text field using its url:

> This module will allow Drupal to replace textarea fields with the
>   CKEditor - a visual HTML editor, usually called a WYSIWYG editor. This
>   HTML text editor brings many of the powerful WYSIWYG editing functions
>   of known desktop editors like Word to the web. It's very fast and
>   doesn't require any kind of installation on the client computer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I know all that stuff, but what I was looking for is the ability to add link directly to the body, without any buttons clicking. I mean user type text in editor(CKeditor or whatever) an just paste(or type) a link and when he save the node - link turn to image.